# Bigint error when copying .csv to postgresql

Tags: postgresql, csv, elixir, ecto, ubuntu-20.04

Trying to import a .csv into my postgres table using the following approach:

> *System: WSL2 - UBUNTU 20.04*

`psql -d db_name --user=username -c "\copy test_list FROM 'testmngrs.csv' delimiter '|' csv;"`

The content format of my .csv:

```
1,Name,name@store_id.com,1234567891,City Name
```

The error I'm receiving:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type bigint:
CONTEXT:  COPY test_list, line 1, column id:
```

The table:

```
SELECT * FROM test_list;
id | store_id | name | email | phone | city
```

The additional id at the head of the table above was not something created during my initial set up of the table.

My ecto migration file is as follows:
[image: ectomigration]

**I'm not sure what's causing the BigInt error, nor how to avoid it as I copy over the data. I'm also a bit confused as to why there's an additional id column in my table given that it was never defined in my migration**

I'm pretty new to postgresql and elixir / ecto so any assistance is greatly/guidance/context is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto_sql/Ecto.Migration.html#create/2):

> By default, the table will also include an `:id` primary key field that has a type of `:bigserial.`

Ecto assumes you want it to generate the `id` field by default. It's better to just go with it. But you can configure it somewhat counter-intuitively by setting `primary_key: false` [on the table](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto_sql/Ecto.Migration.html#table/2), and `primary_key: true` [on the column](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto_sql/Ecto.Migration.html#add/3):

```elixir
create table(:managers, primary_key: false) do
  add :store_id, :integer, null: false, primary_key: true
  ...
```

Comment: Thank you for that additional context! I ended up dropping the id column and concatenating my .csv into a .sql file to insert into the db.